# GRE mathematics subject test

Tags: application, germany

I received a scaled score of 480 and it seems it is not a nice score for GRE mathematics subject test. Should I include it or should I not include it in my application for masters in astrophysics in Germany. I have a very good score in academics and I have done my Bachelors in Mechanical Engineering?  So my question is whether to include it or not?

Comment: Do German astrophysics programs require the math GRE? If not, why send it (since the score is poor)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't give an answer as to whether you should include it, but note two things.

First 480 is quite a low score, only the 10th percentile.

But, OTOH, the math test is quite difficult, even for those who major in math as an undergraduate. It is very broad.

The number seems low, however, even for an engineering major who should have studied a fair amount of the things that the GRE test emphasizes (Calculus, broadly speaking, and abstract Algebra).

And standards in Germany are quite high, I think, though I don't know anything about how it works in astrophysics.